# How to make the section title to appear in a rectangle of column width?

Tags: posters, section-titles

In [poster-1](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modelo-de-poster-para-o-sbrt-2023/zhkhdgfncghq.pdf), the title of the section like Resumo appears in a blue rectangle whose size is equal to the size of the text. Is it possible to make the titles in this poster to appear like in [poster-2](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/stockholm-university-poster-template/xsrhnggqmcsx.pdf), in which a blue rectangle appears whose size is equal to the column width?

Comment: Hi, since you're not providing an MWE, let alone telling us which document class you're using, we can only guess. Maybe give the class [`modernposter`](https://ctan.org/pkg/modernposter) a try. There the titles seem to have this style by default, at least if you look at the example page on Github.